# Hide Elements from UI in Azure B2C AD Custom Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to hide certain elements from the Azure AD B2C Custom Policies:

1. The ‘Change Email’ button needs to be hidden on the password reset page.
2. The ‘Continue’ button on the enter MFA OTP page needs to be hidden.
3. The ‘Sign-Up Now’ hyperlink needs to be hidden.
4. The ‘Cancel’ button needs to be hidden.
5. ‘Sign in with Social Account’ needs to be hidden.

Is this something that can be done?
If yes, what's the best way of doing the same?

Thanks in advance!

I've tried using the setting.showCancelButton on the FrameworkExtensions page on the TechnicalProfile, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, for the others, I haven't found a link specifying how to do so.

Comment: Custom HTML for the pages, CSS can hide elements.

Comment: Point 1 is a bad idea. What if the user genuinely got the email address wrong and only noticed when the OTP didn't arrive? You then force them down a bad user experience of having to restart the journey again.

Comment: It would be useful add the code you've tried, in your question. It could be just a misconfiguration as `setting.showCancelButton` is the correct metadata

Answer (score 0):

Some of the elements can be easily hidden with changes to your custom policies.
For SignUp hyperlink, there is an [extensive guide with samples on B2C unit-tests github](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests/tree/main/technical-profiles/self-asserted#show-sign-up-link).
In your case:

- 'Sign-Up Now' hyperlink can be hidden by setting metadata attribute `setting.showSignupLink` to false on your technical profile.
- 'Cancel' button can be also hidden by metadata attribute `setting.showCancelButton` set to false

For the other changes, it is only possible by custom CSS applied on the page, which will hide them. See [Microsoft official guide.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#custom-html-and-css-overview)

Note, that if you'll hide `Continue` button on MFA page, you may have to script clicking the button in order for the page to not lose functionality.